# In Hebrews 1:10 Jesus is being addressed as the Creator which is God himself in Genesis

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity

Hebrews 1 is a chapter that is addressed to the Son, which is Jesus himself. But one interesting verse addresses Jesus as the Creator, this is verse 10:

```
And,

    “You, Lord, laid the foundation of the earth in the beginning,
        and the heavens are the work of your hands;
```

Throughout the Gospel book, the only Lord that was mentioned is Jesus. Moreover, the the title of the Hebrews 1 says it so.

Is this a strong evidence of the Trinitarian concept, that both Jesus and The Father **IS** God himself?

(Note i used the word "IS" not "ARE" cause the bible repeatedly mentions that there **IS** only one God but is infinitely complex and not that easy to grasp)

There is an non-Trinitarian answer [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/80439/how-do-unitarians-explain-hebrews-110-12). I would like to know more about the Trinitarian concept on this matter.

Comment: @user47952 The OP has made it very clear they are asking for information about Trinitarian doctrine. Your comments are merely disruptive and argumentative.

Comment: There is more to it than the Trinitarians claim: https://biblehub.com/john/17-21.htm Borrowing pagan doctrines became a common practice of the church sometime after the age of apostles. Bible says that husband and wife become one body. Somehow I do not see duotarian views trying to explain this.

Comment: From the link that you cited, it was explicit that Father is one with Jesus, is this what you mean by pagan?

Comment: @JonesG By pagan I mean borrowing doctrines from other religions. the verse 21 says with mine emphasis: THAT THEY ALL MAY BE ONE; as thou, Father, art in me, and I in thee, THAT THEY ALSO MAY BE ONE IN US. That what King James version reads.

Comment: I dont know which is borrowed if the concept was in the bible? Like the Jesus and The Father is one as you linked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, Jesus Christ is the creator even according to His own Father. Since the Son is the Father's agent in creating the universe and the ages through which it progresses (see 1:2), these words about Jehovah the Creator are fittingly used of Jesus Christ the Son.

In Psalm 102:24 it is "God" who is addressed, but in 102:22 He is identified as "Lord," which is the translation of the Hebrew word for "Jehovah."

In the Septuagint He is addressed as "Lord," that is, kurion. Consistent with his understanding of the Old Testament the writer of the Hebrews recognized Jesus is God and freely used passages of Scripture which speak about Jehovah in talking about Him.

Who else but the Son is both Creator and Lord? Jesus Christ existed before the universe because He created it. It is not everlasting; He is. Hebrews 1;10 is in perfect harmony regarding the Son at John 1:1-3, Colossians 1:16, Revelation 3:14 and here at verse 10.

Since He is Jehovah God, there is no reason to puzzle or wonder why created beings like the angels will bow down and worship Him, confessing Him Lord of lords. This also means that Jesus Christ is not an angel like some organizations teach.

Now, Acts 2:36 was brought up stating, "God has made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both LORD and Messiah." First of all Jesus was born "Lord, Savior and Christ the Lord at Luke 2:11. "for today in the city of David there has been born for you a Savior, WHO IS Christ the Lord."

What Acts 2:36 is teaching is the resurrection of Jesus Christ revealed or established He was Lord and the Christ/Messiah. The Apostle Paul confirms this at Romans 1:3-4. "concerning His Son, who was born of a descendant of David according to the flesh, (why bring up according to the flesh?) Vs4, who was DECLARED the Son of God with power (how?) by the resurrection from the dead, according to the spirit of holiness, Jesus Christ OUR LORD."

Comment: I accepted this as the answer due to the depth of the references cited. This gives more option for cross validation.

Comment: Excellent answer. Concise, yet fully informative. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the larger quote from Hebrews 1:8-12 which, as you have rightly commented, is addressed to the Son:

> But of the Son he says, “**Your throne, O God**, is forever and ever, the scepter of uprightness is the scepter of your kingdom. You have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; therefore God, your God, has anointed you with the oil of gladness beyond your companions.” And, “**You, Lord**, laid the foundation of the earth in the beginning, and the heavens are the work of your hands; they will perish, but you remain; they will all wear out like a garment, like a robe you will roll them up, like a garment they will be changed. But you are the same, and your years will have no end.”

The verses in question (Heb 1:10-12) are a quotation from Psalm 102:24-27:

> “O my God,” I say, “take me not away in the midst of my days— you whose years endure throughout all generations!” Of old you laid the foundation of the earth, and the heavens are the work of your hands. They will perish, but you will remain; they will all wear out like a garment. You will change them like a robe, and they will pass away, but you are the same, and your years have no end.

Notice that the passage in Psalms addresses to "O my God" and in Hebrews to "of the Son he says".  When linked, as this is, to the creative act of "laying the foundation of the earth" and immersed in the eternal nature expressed by "you whose years endure throughout all generations" and "your years have no end" it is, indeed, a strong thread of evidence for the triune nature of the Godhead.

John begins his Gospel in just the same way appealing to the same two elements of creation and eternality:

> **In the beginning** was the Word, and the Word was with God, and **the Word was God**. He was in the beginning with God. All things were made through him, and without him was not any thing made that was made.- John 1:1-3

This Word, this [Logos](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/does-the-definition-of-word-logos-as-used-in-john-signify-the-thought-behind-t), is the Divine mind.  It is not merely the Word as spoken expression but it is inseparable from the thought and intention behind that which is spoken.  As there can be no ontological difference between what an infinite, eternal God of perfect integrity thinks, says, and does and what that God actually is, therefore the Word (Divine thought and intent) was God.

There are those who imagine a time where God the Father existed prior to creating the Word.  This necessitates either diminishing the Word (which some do), adding phrases to the text (as some do), or imagining God existing for a time with neither thought nor intention.

But we have, very clearly "In the beginning God..." prior to creation without beginning or end.  And we have equally clearly "In the beginning was the Word and the Word was with God and the Word was God..." prior to creation and without beginning or end.

**He (the Word)** was in the beginning *with* God.  This beginning is intended to bring us to Genesis 1:1.

The same He (the Word) *was* God at that point.

He both *was* God and also *with* God.

This is why the writer of Hebrews can say some of the same things about the Son as are said of God himself.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I up-voted this, I wish I can check both. Regards